# Auth allow() error

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I ran my login.ctp....it gave me a Fatal error saying "Call to a member function allow() on a non-object" and i dont how to fix it...This is my AppController it had the error in the beforeFilter function:

```
       public $component1 = array(
             'Session', 'Auth' => array(
                                    'loginRedirect' => array(
                                    'controller' => 'users',
                                   'action' => 'home'
                                  ),
            'logoutRedirect' => array(
            'controller' => 'users',
            'action' => 'login'
                  )
               )
           );

         function beforeFilter(){     
         parent::beforeFilter();    
         $this->Auth->allow('add','view');
```

Comment: $components instead of $component1 ?

Answer (score 0):

you should change`public $component1` to `public $components`